# How to change eZPlatform Backoffice SiteAccess?

Tags: ezplatform

I'm new to ezplatform and I have been just thrown in a project involving migration from ez legacy to ez platform.
One problem I've just bumped into is about siteaccess and images.

Example: users have custom images defined in a var directory, let's say `var/news`.
Unfortunately backoffice uses default siteaccess and I don't find a way to modify it without trigger a redirect from `/ez#login` to `/login page`.

I noticed that I can't change backoffice siteaccess in demo platform too.

So I was wondering either if there's a way to achieve this purpose or there's documentation that could help to address such subject?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you have one var directory per site access, that is the issue right? As /ez will use the default one, you have a problem.

I think there is no simple way to manage this use case right now, I think it will be possible to do it with 2.x (ask in Slack)

One complex solution would be to put everything in one var directory and replace in the DB the different paths... :(

(or wait 2.x)